# Alias for parameter Pat

Tags: powershell

We can supply -Pat parameter : `Get-ChildItem -Pat 'C:\'`

I was expecting to see "Pat" as an alias here but "Aliases : None"

```
help gci -Parameter Path
```

So, at which level is defined "Pat"?

Comment: `-Pat` == `-Path`. Powershell will allow the shortest spelling of a flag that is not ambiguous.

Comment: Yes I know, but in fact I would like to see "Pat" somewhere. If "pat" is not an alias, what it is?

Comment: @expirat001 it's an unambiguous abbreviation of an actual parameter - PowerShell looks at it and says "Seems like expirat001 probably meant `Path`, no other parameter names start with `Pat`"

Comment: "pat" is a shortened form of  "path".  It's unambiguous, so Powershell has no problem parsing it.  It's unnecessary to document shortened forms of keywords, and there are too many of them anyway.  This is not like the relationship between "gci" and "get-childitem".

Comment: OK I understand better. Does an alias parameter is considered a partial parameter?

Comment: @expirat001 No - an alias is an alias - a parameter name translation defined explicitly in the param block. A partial parameter is just a string that, when evaluated by the parser, corresponds unambiguously to exactly 1 valid parameter (such as in your example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pat`, in this context, is a *partial parameter name* match.

> So, at which level is defined "Pat"?

**Nowhere!** That's the point :)

When you enter a command, the parser looks at it and tries to resolve the arguments to valid parameters.

If an argument is preceded by `-ParameterName` or `-ParameterAlias` it's as simple as binding the value to that Parameter.

If an argument is preceded by a Parameter name *not* representing a valid parameter name or value, it looks at all parameter and alias names that *start* with that string, and whose type (if present) matches that of the input value. If 1, and only 1 match is found, the argument is bound to that parameter - otherwise you get an `AmbiguousParameter` error:

```
PS C:\> function Test-PartialParam {
>>> param(
>>>   [string]$Path,
>>>   [string]$Parent
>>> )
>>> }
PS C:\> Test-PartialParam -Pa "C:\path\to\something"
Test-PartialParam : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'Pa' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Path -Parent.
At line:1 char:19
+ Test-PartialParam -Pa "C:\path\to\something"
+                   ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-PartialParam], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Test-PartialParam
```